# typescript, how to implement an interface with index types use function expression pattern?

Tags: typescript

I definite a interface like this:

```
export interface IPluck<T, K extends keyof T>{
  (o: T, names: K[]): T[K][];  
}
```

my question is how to implement it with `function expression` pattern, like this:

```
const pluck_v2: IPluck<?, ?> = (o, names) => {
  return names.map(name => o[name]);        
};
```

for now, it's not correct. I don't know what arguments should be pass to `IPluck`.

here is the rest code:

```
export interface IPerson{
    name: string;
    age: number;
  }

  const me: IPerson = {
    name: 'novaline',
    age: 23
  };

  console.log(pluck(me, ['name']));
```

P.S. My English is poor. Anyone can help me edit the question title. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%20%20%20%20export%20interface%20IPerson%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20age%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20me%3A%20IPerson%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'novaline'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20age%3A%2023%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20function%20pluck%3CT%2C%20K%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E(o%3A%20T%2C%20names%3A%20K%5B%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20names.map(name%20%3D%3E%20o%5Bname%5D)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20pluck2%20%3D%20%3CT%2C%20K%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E(o%3A%20T%2C%20names%3A%20K%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20names.map(name%20%3D%3E%20o%5Bname%5D)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%20IPluck%20%3D%20%3CT%2C%20K%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E(o%3A%20T%2C%20names%3A%20K%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20T%5BK%5D%5B%5D%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20pluck3%3A%20IPluck%20%3D%20(o%3A%20IPerson%2C%20names%3A%20(keyof%20IPerson)%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20names.map(name%20%3D%3E%20o%5Bname%5D)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(pluck(me%2C%20%5B'name'%5D))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(pluck2(me%2C%20%5B'name'%5D))%3B) is your friend:

```
export interface IPerson {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

const me: IPerson = {
    name: 'novaline',
    age: 23
};
function pluck<T, K extends keyof T>(o: T, names: K[]) {
    return names.map(name => o[name]);        
};

const pluck2 = <T, K extends keyof T>(o: T, names: K[]) => {
    return names.map(name => o[name]);            
}
type IPluck = <T, K extends keyof T>(o: T, names: K[]) => T[K][] 
const pluck3: IPluck
  = (o, names) => {
    return names.map(name => o[name]);                
}
console.log(pluck(me, ['name']));
console.log(pluck2(me, ['name']));
```

Explanation: no matter it is function declaration or function expression, you are expressing the type of the function, not the variable. That's why the generic should go with the function.

Comment: I want definite `pluck_v2` firstly and assign it. like:
`const fn: (n: string) => string = (name: string): string => name;`

Comment: The type is just `let pluck3: <T, K extends keyof T>(o: T, names: K[]) => T[K][]`

Comment: yeah, I know, so I write an interface for this signature. But how can I implement with function expression. like `const pluck_v2: IPluck = () => {}`, just like the `fn` example

Comment: Can you replace the definition part `<T, K extends keyof T>(o: T, names: K[])` with my interface `IPluck`?

Comment: I see, you have to use `type` instead of `interface` in this case. Updating answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147425/discussion-between-novaline-and-unional).